# Calculator to Take a New Number

Tags: c#, winforms

After I click the equal button or enter (keyboard) I want my calculator to take a new number, basically as if nothing was in the TextBox, even though the answer is still showing.

Currently, all the numbers stay and the new number is added to the end. After the calculation, if I click on a number button or numpad (keyboard) I want it to clear the TextBox and add the new number.

For example, 2 + 2 = 4, when I enter a new number like 5 the TextBox will not clear the number (4) that is already in the TextBox after clicking equals or enter (keyboard), the TextBox thinks I want it to say 45 but I want the number to be cleared as soon as I enter a new number, only after clicking on equals or enter (keyboard).

If you do not mind, would you also give me an example of what you would do using my code to fix this issue.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Double value = 0;
    String operation = "";
    bool operation_pressed = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((textBoxResult.Text == "0")||(operation_pressed))
            textBoxResult.Clear();
        operation_pressed = false;
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if (b.Text == ".")
        {
            if (!textBoxResult.Text.Contains("."))
            textBoxResult.Text = textBoxResult.Text + b.Text;
        }
        else
                textBoxResult.Text = textBoxResult.Text + b.Text;
    }
    private void operator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if (value != 0)
        {
            buttonEqual.PerformClick();
            operation_pressed = true;
            operation = b.Text;
            labelEquation.Text = value + " " + operation;
        }
        else
        {
            operation = b.Text;
            value = Double.Parse(textBoxResult.Text);
            operation_pressed = true;
            labelEquation.Text = value + " " + operation;
        }
    }
    private void buttonEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelEquation.Text = "";
        switch(operation)
        {
            case "+":
                textBoxResult.Text = (value + Double.Parse(textBoxResult.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "-":
                textBoxResult.Text = (value - Double.Parse(textBoxResult.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "*":
                textBoxResult.Text = (value * Double.Parse(textBoxResult.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "/":
                textBoxResult.Text = (value / Double.Parse(textBoxResult.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        value = Doudble.Parse(textBoxResult.Text);
        operation = "";
    }
    private void buttonClearEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxResult.Text = "0";
    }
    private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxResult.Text = "0";
        value = 0;
        labelEquation.Text = "";
    }
    private void keyboard_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyChar.ToString())
        {
            case "0":
                buttonZero.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "1":
                buttonOne.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "2":
                buttonTwo.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "3":
                buttonThree.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "4":
                buttonFour.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "5":
                buttonFive.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "7":
                buttonSeven.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "8":
                buttonEight.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "9":
                buttonNine.PerformClick();
                break;
            case ".":
                buttonPeriod.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "+":
                buttonAddition.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "-":
                buttonMinus.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "*":
                buttonMultiply.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "/":
                buttonDivide.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "=":
                buttonEqual.PerformClick();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have a *clear* flag. A boolean value. When *enter* or *=* is been pressed set the flag to true. When a number is been entered check the flag. If it is true clear the textbox, enter the value and set the flag to false again.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε - I am not sure how to do that since am new to computer programming, I watched a YouTube video for this tutorial. Would you be so kind and demonstrate what I need to do with my code that I have used? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The calculator program is a nice idea **but** it is way more complicated than you think it is. An example. 3 + 4 * 5 can be interpreted as (3 + 4) * 5 or the correct one 3 + (4 * 5). What happens if you have a larger expresion 3 + 4 / 5 + 6 * 7 / 8 etc You get the point.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε - I understand, I am only needing to clear the TextBox after equals as been activated and once a new number has been entered.

Comment: Oops! You have already a boolean variable for that. Didn't see it. Add *operation_pressed = true;* in the end of *buttonEqual_Click()* sub after *operation = "";*.